# Encountering the error of SyntaxError: can't assign to expression on assigning hexadecimal values to a buffer variable

Tags: python

I am trying to emulate this statement

```c
byte buf0[4] = {0x55, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFE};
```

into python which I have replicated using

```py
bytes (buf0) = (0x55, 0x00, 0x01,0xFE)
```

.However this returns a Syntax error that says

```py
SyntaxError: can't assign to expression on assigning hexadecimal values to a buffer variable
```

Can someone please tell me what may be going wrong and how can I correct it.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Which language is the first statement in? What should the Python code do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write something in python you need to obey its syntax. Also you need to realise that variable declarations are often also assignments.

Did you mean this?

```py
buf0 = (0x55, 0x00, 0x01,0xFE)
```

Comment: This creates a 4-tuple of `int`s, not a sequence of bytes. A tuple of bytes would be `buf0 = (b'\x55', b'\x00', b'\x01', b'\xfe')`

Comment: Ok, but in what way would this not be what the OP requires?

Comment: Their question is unclear, so it could be exactly what they want, or not. They seem to want `bytes`, not `int`s; but really, let's wait for them to clarify.

Comment: Yes lets. In the meantime, I've simply taken what they have and just removed a small amount of extraneous stuff to end up with something which is valid in python.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

```py
buf0 = b'\x55\x00\x01\xFE'
```

Or, equivalently,

```py
buf0 = bytes([0x55, 0x00, 0x01, 0xFE])
```